# Hierarchical tree view in VF with custom object

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-object

I have a custom object that shows a relationship between a contact or account with another contact or account. I would like to display these custom objects in a hierarchical tree display. My VF page would be displayed on an account or contact page so the root node would be that contact or account. I would also want to implement a lazy read so that I can quickly load just the direct relationships that contact or account has. I want to make it grow as the user expands names to see relationships those people or organizations have. I've attached a picture that will hopefully explain what I'm wanting

[image]

What would be the best approach as far as building a tree display? I have looked at DynaTree, Java TreeView and FuelUX Tree documentation but none of those seem to work with a salesforce custom object in the node.

Comment: In case you don't get a more complete answer here is one approach. I used [jQuery TreeTable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/) because I wanted the table columns. The general approach was to add static @RemoteAction methods to the controller that returned JSON versions of the underlying data that met the needs of the TreeTable JavaScript. The code ends up looking something like [this table example](http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/connecting-datatables-to-json-generated-by-apex/). You'll need to get fairly good with JSON and JavaScript though to get it working.